# Lipschitz constant for operator norm

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, lipschitz-functions, singular-values

I want to show that $\|\cdot \|_{\rm op}$ (largest singular value) is a Lipschitz function on the set of $m \times n$ real matrices, $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

I see often people citing Lidskii's inequality to prove it, but I think the following also shows it: use the variational characterization of the operator norm: 
$$
\|A\|_{\rm op} = \sup_{\|x\| =\|y\| = 1} x^T Ay
$$
Fix two matrices $A, B$, and without loss suppose 
$$
|\|A\|_{\rm op} - \|B\|_{\rm op}| = \|A\|_{\rm op} - \|B\|_{\rm op}.
$$
Then, 
there is $\|u\| = \|v\| = 1$ so that
$$
\|A\|_{\rm op} - \|B\|_{\rm op} \leq u^T(A - B) v \leq \|uv^T\|_F \|A-B\|_F = \|A-B\|_F.
$$
Hence, 
$$
|\|A\|_{\rm op} - \|B\|_{\rm op}| \leq \|A-B\|_F.
$$
Does this not imply that the operator norm is $1$-Lipschitz with respect to the usual (Frobenius) norm on $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$?

Comment: How do you get $\|A\|-\|B\|\leq u^T(A-B)v$? Is there a guarantee that $u$ and $v$ that realize the supremum in $u^TAv$ and in $u^TBv$ can be the same?

Comment: No. But you do not need that. You have the existence of such maximal $u, v$ for $A$. In other words, certainly by compactness or singular value decomposition one has $u, v$ so that $\|A\| = u^T A v$. On the other hand $\|B\| \geq u^T Bv$. Therefore the inequality follows, no?

Comment: Ok. In that case it should be fine. But one more detail: What about the next inequality? How do you get $\|uv^T\|_F$ separated from $A-B$?

Comment: $u^T(A-B)v = \sum_{i,j} (A - B)_{ij} (uv^T)_{ij} \leq \|A- B\|_{F} \|uv^T\|_{F}$, by Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Alternatively, one can just use $u^T(A-B)v = \langle uv^T, A-B \rangle$ and vector duality in $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ (i.e. the $\ell_2$-norm $\|\cdot\|_F$ is self dual.)

Comment: Now I am convinced.